# How to build a barplot on non numeric values?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have the following columns “sex”,”profession”,”name”.
I need to plot a barplot to compare the amount of people of different sex depending on the profession. So the barplot will look something like this
https://i2.wp.com/datavizpyr.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/grouped_barplot_Seaborn_barplot_Python.png?fit=601%2C481&ssl=1

But of course on the x-axis should be “professions” and on the y number of females and males

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['profession'], df['sex']).plot.bar()`

Comment: @Quang Hoang thank you,it works! But is there a way to do it by using seaborn tools?

Answer (score 3):

With Pandas:

```
pd.crosstab(df['profession'], df['sex']).plot.bar()
```

With Seaborn:

```
sns.countplot(x='profession', hue='sex', data=df)
```